# Modifying mutable object in completion handler

Tags: ios, thread-safety, gamekit, objective-c-blocks

I have a question about thread safety of the following code example from Apple (from GameKit programming guide)

This is to load achievements from game center and save it locally:

Step 1)  Add a mutable dictionary property to your class that report achievements. This dictionary stores the collection of achievement objects.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *achievementsDictionary;
```

Step 2) Initialize the achievements dictionary.

```
achievementsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Step 3) Modify your code that loads loads achievement data to add the achievement objects to the dictionary.

```
{
    [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error == nil)
            {
                for (GKAchievement* achievement in achievements)
                    [achievementsDictionary setObject: achievement forKey: achievement.identifier];
            }
        }];
```

My question is as follows - achievementsDictionary object is being modified in the completion handler, without any locks of sort.  Is this allowed because completion handlers are a block of work that will be guaranteed by iOS to be executed as unit on the main thread?  And never run into thread safety issues?

In another Apple sample code (GKTapper), this part is handled differently:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* earnedAchievementCache; // note this is atomic
```

Then in the handler:

```
[GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error)
        {
            if(error == NULL)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary* tempCache= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: [scores count]];
                for (GKAchievement* score in scores)
                {
                    [tempCache setObject: score forKey: score.identifier];
                }
                self.earnedAchievementCache= tempCache;
            }
        }];
```

So why the different style, and is one way more correct than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this allowed because completion handlers are a block of work that will be guaranteed by iOS to be executed as unit on the main thread? And never run into thread safety issues?

This is definitely not the case here. The documentation for `-loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:` explicitly warns that the completion handler might be called on a thread other than the one you started the load from.

Apple's "Threading Programming Guide" classifies `NSMutableDictionary` among thread-unsafe classes, but qualifies this with, "In most cases, you can use these classes from any thread as long as you use them from only one thread at a time."

So, if both apps are designed such that nothing will be working with the achievement cache till the worker task has finished updating it, then no synchronization would be necessary. This is the only way in which I can see the first example as being safe, and it's a tenuous safety.

The latter example looks like it's relying on the atomic property support to make the switcheroo between the old cache and the new cache. This should be safe, provided all access to the property is via its accessors rather than direct ivar access. This is because the accessors are synchronized with respect to each other, so you do not risk seeing a half-set value. Also, the getter retains and autoreleases the returned value, so that code with the old version will be able to finish working with it without crashing because it was released in the middle of its work. A nonatomic getter simply returns the object directly, which means that it could be deallocated out from under your code if a new value were set for that property by another thread. Direct ivar access can run into the same problem.

I would say the latter example is both correct and elegant, though perhaps a bit over-subtle without a comment explaining how crucial the atomicity of the property is.

Comment: thanks Jeremy. i was also questioning about block completion handlers in general.  If documentation doesn't explicitly say where completion handler is called, is it safe to assume that it's not called in main thread? If it is specified to be called from main queue, then is it safe to do anything inside without worrying about thread safety (assuming all access are from main thread or compl. handler called on main queue).

Comment: If it doesn't specify that your block will be called on the main queue/thread, then you have to take your own measures to ensure it is, if that's what you need. It might actually be called on the main thread, but at that point, that fact is an implementation detail, not part of the API contract, and might change without warning. If it is specified to be called from the main queue, then you can take full advantage of that.

Comment: One last question then - if I change first completion handler to use               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ for (GKAchievement* achievement in achievements)
  [achievementsDictionary setObject: achievement forKey: achievement.identifier]; });)
 will this code be threadsafe as well?  I remember reading something about this not being safe..

Comment: "Threadsafe" isn't a simple binary quality. It's heavily context-dependent. That's part of why it's so easy to mess up multi-threaded apps. If you can guarantee that all access to your `achievementsDictionary` happens on the main thread only, then forcing those changes to the main thread serializes them relative to all other accesses, so you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for your patience! i think i understand this better now.